# Two different speakers setup

Tags: windows-8, audio, speakers, audio-streaming, playback

I have two different speakers, and they are different brands. They both work on my desktop. I can plug both of them in but the sound only comes out of the one I set to default through Playback Devices. How do I send the sound through both speakers so both of them are outputting the sound coming from the desktop?

If this wasn't clear, throw me a comment below.

Comment: What do you mean you can plug them both in?  How are you connecting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cheat. You get a stereo audio splitter, plug that in where your output connector is, and plug in both speakers into it.

[image]

Its usually a little box like this

[image]

Or a cable with two female ends and one male one like this

Comment: Is there a way to do this wirelessly?